# How to write spaces between Korean words with XeCJK?

Tags: spacing, cjk, xecjk

I'm just trying to get LaTeX output spaces between Korean words. 
At the moment all it can do is to give long chains of syllables just like
in Chinese or in Japanese, ignoring all the spaces I set.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[boldfont,slantfont]{xeCJK} 
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\setCJKmainfont{Batang} % for \rmfamily 

\begin{document}
좋은 아침입니다! 안녕하세요, 저의 이름은 김 입니다.%"Good Morning! My Name is Kim." in Korean
\end{document}
```

The text output is just like: 좋은아침입니다! 안녕하세요, 저의이름은김입니다. So, spaces will only be processed after punctuation marks.

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't tell what exactly.

Comment: Now `xeCJK` is updated to provide `space` option and `\CJKspace`. Check out the code at http://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/source/checkout . The package will be uploaded to CTAN some time later.

Comment: Now xeCJK 2.4.2 is uploaded to CTAN.

Answer (score 6):

Quick fix:

```
\makeatletter
\let\xeCJK@ignorespaces\relax
\makeatother
```

---

In `xeCJK` 2.4.1 (2011/05/20), you can use:

```
\usepackage[space]{xeCJK}
\renewcommand\CJKglue{}% get proper linebreaking if spaces are provided
```

or use `\CJKspace` to allow spaces between CJK charecters.

Before the new `xeCJK` updated to CTAN, you can always get the latest code through SVN:

http://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/source/checkout

Comment: While you're at it, please change the explicit character class assignments by using the allocation mechanism with `\newXeTeXintercharclass` so that xeCJK can cooperate with other packages that use character classes.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, it does be in the todo list, but it's not urgent. And AFAIK, it's more difficult than you say. The situation is a bit complex: class 1, 2 and 3 are *predefined* in XeTeX for CJK scripts and punctuations (although we redefined them), and others should be allocated with `\newXeTeXintercharclass`. Furthermore, this does little help with compatibility with other packages (e.g. `polyglossia`) --- once we allocate a new character class, we often have to define `\XeTeXinterchartoks` for **all former character classes** to make it work well.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just copied in the modifications you gave me and Tada! it's working now. Exactly what I was looking for. I'll notify you, if there are any further problems comming up with this new command being included now.

Comment: @sunny: It isn't a new command in fact. In `CJK` package there are `\CJKspace` and `\CJKnospace`, and this is just a reimplementation of that. Prof. Sun, the author of `xeCJK`, also took part in development of some parts of `CJK` package. `xeCJK` borrows many things from `CJK`.