# Turning Chinese line breaks on and off

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, cjk

I am typesetting a document in Chinese with spaces between words, for the purpose of making it easier for learners. Because of this, I am typesetting most of my document with no line-breaks between words. Because Chinese words are generally pretty short, this will generally not cause any big problems.

However, in some parts of my document, I  will need to use Chinese line breaks, as defined by \XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh" (or similar) to avoid over-filled boxes. Basically, those are regular paragraphs of Chinese text, which will not break at all without this option turned on. However, this appears to be a document specific parameter that I can not easily change in only parts of the document.

Any ideas for how I can deal with this problem?

I added to my comment below that I would like to type Chinese text without spaces, as "我喜欢学中文", in which case line breaks would use a Chinese locale, as well as space delimited Chinese (non-standard) "我 喜欢 学 中文", in which case no line breaks are allowed in the middle of words (or possibly only allowed with very high tolerance).

If I just turn on \XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh" (or use a CJK package, I believe), all words will be broken according to Chinese rules, in which case I risk getting the "中文" in "我 喜欢 学 中文" broken over two lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)

Comment: Added clarification as I believe that questions are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use more than one paragraph Chinese, use our `xeCJK` package.

For totally Chinese document, use our documents or packages in `ctex` bundle. It is based on `xeCJK`.

I have explained this topic in a previous question:

[How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex/17637#17637)

Of course `xeCJK` solve the problem about line breaking. You don't need `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` with `xeCJK`; and `xeCJK` does not change the `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` either.

---

You don't need to care about the line break locale if you use

```
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
```

it does nothing to do with western languages as far as I know. Similarly, using `xeCJK` you also don't need to turn off it. Non-CJK text would be untouched. With `xeCJK`, it is much easier to set the fonts for Chinese without changing western texts, and you'll get better result for puncuations.

For completeness only, I'll say that you can use `\makexeCJKactive` and `\makexeCJKinactive` to turn on and off the functions of `xeCJK`.

Note: `xeCJK` is not completely compatible with `polyglossia` package for some of the languages. If you meet more problems, ask more questions or contact me. (I am currently the main maintainer of `xeCJK`.)

---

For updated question, see this previous question:

[How to write spaces between Korean words with XeCJK?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17292/how-to-write-spaces-between-korean-words-with-xecjk)

You can use `space` and `nospace` options in `xeCJK`, and `\CJKspace` and `\CJKnospace` option, just like `CJK` package do.

I think it is not suggested to suppress line breaks between Chinese characters even if you use `\CJKspace` to allow spaces between Chinese characters. If you insist, you can change the definition of `\CJKglue` to empty. You can read [the document of `xeCJK`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf) if you are not sure about the options and commands.

After all, an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}[2011/05/20]
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}
在普通文字之间没有空格
可以避免源代码折行造成
的问题。

\CJKspace
如果 需要 也 可以 保留 空格。
这 对于 汉语 分词 研究 或许 是 有益的。
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that I would like to typeset Chinese next both with and without line breaks within words. E.g. space-delimited Chinese text of the type "我 喜欢 学 中文" should never line-break at all within words, while another paragraph with the tex "我喜欢学中文" should use regular Chinese line breaks. Does the  CJK package cover this situation?

Comment: @Carl: Sure. You can use `space` option in `xeCJK`, or use `\CJKspace` and `\CJKnospace` to turn on and off this feature. See this: [How to write spaces between Korean words with XeCJK?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17292/how-to-write-spaces-between-korean-words-with-xecjk)