# Spacing only works in xeCJK for Chinese and Japanses but not Korean

Tags: spacing, cjk, xecjk

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Batang}

\CJKspace
\begin{document}

一二三四五

一 二 三 四 五

あいうえお

あ い う え お

일이삼사오

일 이 삼 사 오

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to write something with some Chinese, Japanese, and Korean in it. As you may know, among the three, Korean is the one that requires spacing between the words, but not the other two. I have the code written as above, and for Chinese and Japanese, the result is as expected, with spaces, but for Korean, the spaces in the last line are ignored.

I've read [the other post about putting spaces between Korean words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17292/how-to-write-spaces-between-korean-words-with-xecjk/), but it doesn't seem to work for me. So I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry that it is a bug of `xeCJK` since version `2012/12/07 v3.1.1`. We'll fix it soon.

Before we fix it, you could check out the [SVN version](http://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/source/checkout) or temporaly use this quick fix:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnnn { "AC00 } {1} { "D7A3 } { \char_set_catcode_letter:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

**Update:**

In fact it is [a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/84/) of XeTeX. I've just reported it. Anyway, we'll still have a patch in `xeCJK` package.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. The quick fix works like a charm. I'll be looking out for upcoming updates.