# spacing between Japanese words (xelatex)

Tags: spacing, xetex, cjk

I'm working with Xelatex 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux), compiling my .tex file and getting a simple .pdf file.

I'm stuck on the following problem, occuring in a simple Japanese sentence. I want something like :

> ABC せんつぶ まいたら ひとつぶに なあれ ひとつぶ まいたら

But all I get is (without any space between the Japanese words) :

> ABC せんつぶまいたらひとつぶになあれひとつぶまいたら

I get the spaces only by using the \; "trick" but I would like to avoid it :

```
ABC せんつ\;ぶまいたら\;ひとつぶに\;なあれ\;ひとつぶ\;まいたら
```

I'm an absolute newbie and don't know how to handle this problem. Any help would be appreciated !

---

My .tex file :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Sazanami Mincho}
\setmainfont{Sazanami Mincho}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
ABC せんつぶ まいたら ひとつぶに なあれ ひとつぶ まいたら
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get it, [thanks to this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130612/spacing-only-works-in-xecjk-for-chinese-and-japanses-but-not-korean).

Just add \CJKspace this way :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Sazanami Mincho}
\setmainfont{Sazanami Mincho}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\CJKspace
\begin{document}
ABC せんつぶ\;まいたら ひとつぶに なあれ ひとつぶ まいたら
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, you got it.